# VBA Powerpoint - get Parameters from Shape and hand over to another shape

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to build a VBA-Powerpoint macro which gives the parameters of an activated shape (by mouse) back.

The idea is to hand over the parameters with a second macro to another shape. This need to be activated before (by mouse).

Steps:

1. Click on a shape
2. Activate Macro selectTest -> Feedback Parameters
3. Click on second shape
4. Acitvate second macro -> hand over parameters
5. Both shapes have same size and position

My problem is that i dont understand how to check if the paramters are in my Dim and how to hand it over.

I am new to VBA and trying to learn :)

```
Dim width   As Double
Dim height  As Double
Dim x       As Double
Dim y       As Double


Sub selectTest()
    With PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        width = .width
        height = .height
        x = .Left
        y = .Top
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains a declaration of global variables and two procedures - `getParams` to save parameters of a shape (coordinates and dimensions) to global variables and `setParams` to assign saved parameters to another shape. Global (defined outside a sub or function) variables retain their values between calls to a sub or function.
At the beginning of each procedure we check if any figure is selected (the result of this expression must be `False`): `ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone`. The `setParams` procedure also checks if the parameters were previously saved. To do this, the variable `paramsFilled` is used, the default value of which is `False`, but after saving the parameters it is assigned the value `True`.
If the above checks are passed successfully, the main code is executed - either assigning values of the shape properties to the variables or vice versa assigning the values saved in the variables to the shape properties.
`ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)` means that we select the first shape from the selected ones ([a shape range can contain as few as a single shape or as many as all the shapes on the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange)).
If the checks are unsuccessful, the corresponding messages are output.

```
Dim width   As Double
Dim height  As Double
Dim x       As Double
Dim y       As Double
Dim paramsFilled As Boolean 'if true indicates that the parameters have been filled

Sub getParams()
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected", vbCritical
    Else
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            width = .width
            height = .height
            x = .Left
            y = .Top
        End With
    End If
    paramsFilled = True ' the parameters have been saved
End Sub

Sub setParams()
    If Not paramsFilled Then    'check if the parameters are filled in
        MsgBox "Parameters were not saved", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected", vbCritical
    Else
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            .width = width
            .height = height
            .Left = x
            .Top = y
        End With
        paramsFilled = False 'optionally you can reset stored parameters after apply or leave them for future use
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks amazing but can you explan me the code? I dont understand this two things and want to learn so i get better with vba.
Why you need ````paramsFilled````. Why you need this ````ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone````.
Have you an advice how can i find out that i need ````ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)```` with the  (1).  The object catalog is lil bit confusing for me at the moment.

Comment: Explained as best I could :) - see text above the solution